# Titanium Mobile: Closing activity indicator from with another controller

Tags: mobile, android-activity, titanium

I have 4 controllers, `index.js`, `token.js`, `main.js` and `token.js`.  Index checks for authentication and redirects to `token.js` for user details if no details is found. If authentication checks then it opens the `main.js` carrying the user details.  Now, just right after `open()` command inside `token.js`, I have this line to show indicator activity:

```
var dispIndicator = Alloy.createController('loader').getView();
dispIndicator.open();
```

Now, I didn't use timeout for indicator because I want to be precise as to when the display is complete behind `main.js` processes.  When everything is fetched and all elements are ready, inside `main.js` I have this lines to close the indicator:

```
var dispIndicator = Alloy.createController('loader').getView();
dispIndicator.close(); // also tried hide();
```

However, this doesn't work but rather gives an `undefined` error.

How can I close the loader from within main controller?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use alloy.js file and create global functions to show and hide loading indicator. I've decided to use global event listener to hide loader:

**alloy.js**

```
var loaders = [];
Alloy.Globals.loading = function(view) {
  if (!view.hasLoading) {
    var loading = Alloy.createController('loading');
    loaders.push({
      view: view,
      loading: loading.getView()
    });
    loading.indicator.show();
    loading.loading.show();
    view.add(loading.getView());
    view.hasLoading = true;
  }
};

Ti.App.addEventListener('app:loaded', function() {
  for (var i in loaders) {
    if (loaders[i].view && loaders[i].loading) {
      loaders[i].view.remove(loaders[i].loading);
      loaders[i].view.hasLoading = false;
    }
  }
  loaders = [];
});
```